# Sum total rows of hours

Tags: php, mysql, time, sum

I have a table with a column "worked hours" and i want to sum all rows like this:

```
    08:00 
    02:00 
    03:30
Total: 13:30
```

And this is my sql select code

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sohy_works WHERE data_raport = '$data' AND codangajat = '$codangajat' ");
```

Comment: Is the selected answer really solution to problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate like this,

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( your_time_field ) ) FROM sohy_works WHERE .....
```

Comment: Can i do this "SELECT *(ALL) SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( your_time_field ) ) FROM sohy_works WHERE ..... ?

Answer (score 2):

Get sum of seconds from db and convert that to hours and minutes:

```
$q = "SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(worked_hours)) FROM sohy_works WHERE data_raport = '$data' AND codangajat = '$codangajat'";

$result = mysql_query( $q );
$sec = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$hours = floor( $sec[0]/3600 );
$minutes = str_pad( floor( $sec[0] % 3600/60 ), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );

echo $hours.':'.$minutes;
```

EDIT:

Hours and minutes can be calculated directly with SQL query like:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `worked_hours` ) ) ) FROM ...
```